# Tor does not restore circuit

Tags: configuration, ubuntu, proxy

I have a HS server for web proxying purposes with an onion address. It's in a test phase at the moment and traffic is low, but from time to time the web server is not reachable using Tor Browser, however it is still accessible from a clearnet browser. 
I have checked Tor logs during connection breakdown:

```
Dec 28 11:05:09.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
Dec 28 12:15:36.000 [notice] Tor has not observed any network activity for the past 632 seconds. Disabling circuit build timeout recording.
Dec 28 12:15:36.000 [notice] Tor now sees network activity. Restoring circuit build timeout recording. Network was down for 632 seconds during 1 circuit attempts.
```

Restarting Tor and then Nginx solves the problem. What else can I check to figure out where the problem is, or how to fix it.
I don't know if it's relevant but IPv6 routing is not working because my hosting provider doesn't support it yet.

Server is Ubuntu 14.04, Tor v0.2.7.6, nginx/1.4.6

Answer (score -1):

You have a 2-part issue. First, tune-up your sysctl's for a good network throughput. Second - tune up your `torrc` for circuit timeouts e.t.c. Also make an ORport reachable from clearnet - it will eliminate the issue. Post your `sysctl -a` and `torrc` if you need specific help - I'll be glad to help!

Comment: They have a hidden service, adding an orport will harm their anonymity. Can you *please* stop giving out harmful advice to users?

Comment: @canonizingironize please, don't make a buzz out of nothing: ORPort is not harming a HS host, if tuned properly. Please prove yourself if you think that it's a concern

Comment: [RiseUp Onion Service Best Practice Guide](https://riseup.net/en/security/network-security/tor/onionservices-best-practices#dont-run-a-relay-at-the-same-time) as linked to by the [Tor Project Hidden Service Configuration Instructions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html#three). Please stop providing harmful advice.

Comment: if you're about "Don’t run a relay at the same time
Do not run a relay and an onion service on the same instance. Having a relay and an onion service on same IP and/or machine helps traffic correlation and fingerprinting. However, Tor is smart enough to not choose itself as a node for the circuit so it’s not a disaster but ideally you want to avoid it." - hmm, take a look at the word *ideally*. As old good times server definition: it's a dedicated hardware instance that provides a single service.

Comment: and if your HS webserver - or *any* server - is leaky about revealing your real IP - no "no-running-a-relay" or similar tactiks will save you. Soon I'll release my project for Kickstarter - you'll see the *actual* implementation of what I'm saying in action

Comment: You don't understand the problem. Dunning-Kruger or actual malice? I can't tell anymore.

Comment: things like DefecTor aren't are miracle too, but they are *hypothetical*. At least for now they're not a prime danger